# Application Context not loaded while running JUnit in a Spring Boot Web Application

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I am trying to build a simple web application with Spring Boot 1.3.5 using Java 1.8.
Though the application works alright. But I am having trouble getting my JUnits to run. Have tried finding solution for this, but most of the answers I saw was mainly for Integration testing which I do not want to do. I need simple JUnit test on my methods in my service layer with some mocking. But I don't seem to get it right. JUnits fail with below error. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

My JUnit Class is as below where right now I am just checking if the objects are created or not

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class ScheduledServiceImplTest{

    @Autowired
    private ScheduledService scheduledService;
    @Mock
    private MyDAO mockMyDAO;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMockCreation(){
        assertNotNull(mockMyDAO);
        assertNotNull(scheduledService);
    }
}
```

My Application.java is as below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace below:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: hi, updated the full stack trace now. Thanks for looking :)

Comment: to test the service layer i dont think you have to provide the context configuration class. Also, why are you mocking and autowiring at the same time? those two are mutually exclusive! autowiring would inject a real instance while mocking creates a mock (and not a real instance)

Comment: To have your context loaded add `@WebAppConfiguration` to your test. But if you only want a unit test then write a unit test and not an integration test.

Comment: @RahulSharma I have tried removing the context config as well. And you are right about auto wiring and mocking. I have it commented in my working copy. Still I get the same error.

Comment: @M.Deinum adding WebAppConfiguration results in an error which asks me to add ContextConfiguration annotation. Even after adding that I get all sorts of beancreaitonexceptions related to datasource which I don't want.

Comment: `A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling`, I think the `SpringBootServletInitializer ` requires a container to run, so I dont think you can spin up a test context using it, maybe use the embdeded tomcat instead.

Comment: @Magnus But wouldn't that mean I end up writing an Integration test than an JUnit. Or should I simply go creating my own objects instead of using Spring and then do unit testing of my individual components?

Comment: @immzi, once you start involving a spring-context I would says you are already writing an integration test, regardless of what type of context it is.

Comment: That depends on what you want to test. If it is only your service yes then do so, if you want an integration test you want the context. So it depends on what kind of these you are writing. Also adding the earlier mentioned annotation should work, if it doesn't you changed different things as well. Also I suggest a read of the testing chapter of the spring boot reference guide.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your suggestion. But lets say if I want to go with integration testing, then also after having webAppConfiguration and ContextConfiguration, am getting errors related to DataSource initialization. Whereas I have given the necessary config for datasource in my application.properties. I have followed all the resources available and all tell the same. I even tried giving separate properties for test as well and included it using TestPropertySource annotation

Comment: can you post what is in your service? If you are testing the service, do you have all the dependencies mocked?

Comment: You don't need `ContextConfiguration` as you already have `SpringApplicationConfiguration`.